# vector of objects , delete and place objects

Tags: c++, object, vector, element

I want to have a vector of vector of objects,lets say a 2d vector of chessPiece class.

I want to be able for each position in the vector to check if there is a chessPiece or not inside it.Also I want to change it for example place a new ChessPiece object in a vector position or deleting it but without changing the size of the 2D vector.

What should I do?
Can I fill a 2D vector with null objects? Because in the beginning I only have 32/64 chesspieces in a board.However after a move I want for example the `vector<vector<Piece> >[1][0]` to take the object from `vector<vector<Piece> >[0][0]` and then delete the object of `vector<vector<Piece> >[1][0]`.

Comment: Why not use a 2d array if you know the number of elements beforehand?

Comment: keep a char for empty chess place and instead of deleting , change it to that char

Comment: because vectors are good with garbage collection.I want to use a ChessPiece object and not a char,because the object has properties like vertices,color etc!

Comment: You can easily delete the 2D array when needed. Using a 2D array you won't have the resizing issues of vectors and you can easily move things around / represent empty positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if you still want a 2D vector, you can do it like that:

```
vector< vector< ChessPiece* > > board;

int main()
{
     board.resize( 8 );
     for( int i = 0; i < board.size(); ++i )
     {
         board[i].resize( 8 );
         board[i].assign( 8, NULL );
     }

     board[0][0] = new ChessPiece();
     delete board[0][0];


return 0;
}
```

You should allocate memory for your pointers, like I did and then for every ceil you can allocate a chess piece (using 'new') or delete (using 'delete')

Comment: a 32*32 chess board? Anyway, I think the right initialization is `vector< vector< ChessPiece* > > board(8, std::vector<ChessPiece*>(8));`

Comment: Anyway, you don't need those calls to resize and the loops. All you need is what I put in my first comment.